# How do I get the full url of the page I am on in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I need to be able to get at the full URL of the page I am on from a user control.  Is it just a matter of concatenating a bunch of Request variables together?  If so which ones? Or is there a more simpiler way?

Comment: To anyone in a loadbalanced webfarm.. beware the port number that appears when using System.Url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674850/get-original-url-without-non-standard-port-c

Answer (score 160, accepted):

I usually use `Request.Url.ToString()` to get the full url (including querystring), no concatenation required.

Comment: If URL contain '#' then all the character after # will not be included.

Comment: @KrunalSisodiya I don't think that a URL's hash is ever sent to the server, but I could be wrong.

Comment: `Request.Url.ToString()` is not include queryString.

Comment: In .Net Core Request.Url is not available, consider Request.GetDisplayUrl()+'?'+Request.QueryString

Answer (score 356):

Here is a list I normally refer to for this type of information:

```
Request.ApplicationPath :   /virtual_dir
Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath :  /virtual_dir/webapp/page.aspx
Request.FilePath :  /virtual_dir/webapp/page.aspx
Request.Path :  /virtual_dir/webapp/page.aspx
Request.PhysicalApplicationPath :   d:\Inetpub\wwwroot\virtual_dir\
Request.QueryString :   /virtual_dir/webapp/page.aspx?q=qvalue
Request.Url.AbsolutePath :  /virtual_dir/webapp/page.aspx
Request.Url.AbsoluteUri :   http://localhost:2000/virtual_dir/webapp/page.aspx?q=qvalue
Request.Url.Host :  localhost
Request.Url.Authority : localhost:80
Request.Url.LocalPath : /virtual_dir/webapp/page.aspx
Request.Url.PathAndQuery :  /virtual_dir/webapp/page.aspx?q=qvalue
Request.Url.Port :  80
Request.Url.Query : ?q=qvalue
Request.Url.Scheme :    http
Request.Url.Segments :  /
    virtual_dir/
    webapp/
    page.aspx
```

Hopefully you will find this useful!

Comment: 1) There is also Request.RawUrl; 2) Request.Url may throw an exception on 'very bad requested paths'.

Comment: Very helpful answer, but shouldn't the port numbers be consistent to avoid confusion (assuming all the examples are for the same request?e.g, Authority and Port imply port 80 but AbsoluteUri contains port 2000)

Comment: `Request.QueryString` returns `q=qvalue` only

Comment: Working Fine :)

Answer (score 77):

```
Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

This property does everything you need, all in one succinct call.

Comment: +1. This is the best answer. Should be preferred over Request.Url.ToString().

Answer (score 33):

For `ASP.NET Core` you'll need to spell it out:

```
var request = Context.Request;
@($"{ request.Scheme }://{ request.Host }{ request.Path }{ request.QueryString }")
```

Or you can add a using statement to your view:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions
```

then

```
@Context.Request.GetDisplayUrl()
```

The `_ViewImports.cshtml` might be a better place for that `@using`

Comment: Thanks. This helped!

Comment: That should probably be `$"{ request.Scheme }{ Uri.SchemeDelimiter }{ request.Host }{ request.PathBase.Add(request.Path) }{ request.QueryString }"`

Comment: I'm curious, is there ever a time when Uri.SchemeDelimiter is not "://", or is that comment, more of a clean code comment to avoid "magic strings"?

Answer (score 9):

if you need the full URL as everything from the http to the querystring you will need to concatenate the following variables

```
Request.ServerVariables("HTTPS") // to check if it's HTTP or HTTPS
Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") 
Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME") 
Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING")
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account non-standard ports (i.e. not using port 80 for http)

Comment: you could use Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_PORT") for port detection !

Comment: Note that this answer uses VB.Net syntax. In C#, use Request.ServerVariables["HTTPS"] for example.

Answer (score 8):

Request.RawUrl

Comment: this doesn't not return the full url. If the full url is http://www.blah.com/1.1/home/main?a=1 Request.RawUrl will return 1.1/hom/main?a=1

Answer (score 7):

Better to use [`Request.Url.OriginalString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.originalstring.aspx) than `Request.Url.ToString()` (according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.tostring.aspx))

Comment: It's only better if you really require the original string.

Comment: @DirkThe from link to MSDN above: "String returned by the ToString method may contain control characters, which can corrupt the state of a console application. You can use the GetComponents method with the UriFormat.SafeUnescaped format to remove control characters from the returned string."

Comment: Exactly, and that has nothing to do with `OriginalString`.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks guys, I used a combination of both your answers @Christian and @Jonathan for my specific need.

```
"http://" + Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"] +  Request.RawUrl.ToString()
```

I don't need to worry about secure http, needed the servername variable and the RawUrl handles the path from the domain name and includes the querystring if present.

Comment: You should also know that RawUrl, unlike Request.Url, represents the original, unmapped request url if url mapping is being used.

Comment: SERVER_NAME often does not return the "real" URL used by the client. HTTP_HOST is probably the better form if going to dig in directly.. also misses out simple HTTP-to-another-port.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the port number also, you can use

```
Request.Url.Authority
```

Example:

```
string url = Request.Url.Authority + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.ToString();

if (Request.ServerVariables["HTTPS"] == "on")
{
    url = "https://" + url;
}
else 
{
    url = "http://" + url;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following -

```
var FullUrl = Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToString();
var ID = FullUrl.Split('/').Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

In .Net Core or .Net 5+ for [HttpRequest class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest?view=aspnetcore-8.0) Request.Url is not available, to have full url including query string consider

```
var fullUrl= Request.GetDisplayUrl()+'?'+Request.QueryString
```