# How to Get Current Browser URL in Code Behind

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

New to the Browser control in WP8. How is it possible to determine the current browser url? From an old WP7 solution I am using

```
Browser.Source.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
```

should this be updated for WP8?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the full url of the page I am on in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40680/how-do-i-get-the-full-url-of-the-page-i-am-on-in-c-sharp)

Comment: It should work - have you tried it?