# Getting the link for a virtual directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written a server in C# for a JS client.
The Solution consists restApi BL and DAL.

The BL creates links for  images stored on a virtual directory, on the server.
The JS and the server code, are stored in the same directory.

When I build the string of the link I use this line of code:

```
string keyImageName = Settings.Default.ServerUrl  + 
    Settings.Default.KeyImagesFolder + relatedFinding.KeyImagePath;`
```

where KeyImageFolder is a virtual directory.

It works fine, but my problem is that the website has multiple Amazon instances, one for each geographical zone , so every time I deploy, I need to change the ip in the settings.it's annoying.

Is there a way to get the virtual directory's url, specifically for each machine?

if the JS is installed on the same machine as the server, does it really need a full path?

Many thanks

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40680/how-do-i-get-the-full-url-of-the-page-i-am-on-in-c-sharp).

Comment: you can read public IP of that instance and if IIS points to root path, then you can directly use that IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need to get the physical path for the file or directory that you want to generate a url for. This can be done within a Page object using [Request.ApplicationPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.applicationpath(v=vs.110).aspx).

Next, this path can be converted to a url path using the [Server.MapPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx) function. This will take into account if there are more than one websites tied to the same path in IIS.

```
var physicalPath = Path.Combine(Request.ApplicationPath, Settings.Default.KeyImagesFolder, relatedFinding.KeyImagePath);
var resourceUrl = Server.MapPath(physicalPath);
```