# jQuery getScript failing

Tags: c#, jquery

So i have three files.

**html** has:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/custom-notebook.js"></script>`

**custom-notebook.js** line gives a 404 not found:

`$.getScript('Scripts/custom-notebook-services.js'); //this gives 404`

**1.** custom-notebook-services.js exists. It used to work but I changed html pathing to include the `~/` because I have a virtual application (yes MVC C#)..

**2.** Now nothing I do works (yes also searched around).

- I have tried `$.getScript('../Scripts/custom-notebook-services.js');`
- and `$.getScript('../../Scripts/custom-notebook-services.js');`
- and `$.getScript('/Scripts/custom-notebook-services.js');`

**No luck:**

Always gives me a 404 with path

`domain.com/Controller/Scripts/custom-notebook-services.js`

...instead of proper path:

`domain.com/Scripts/custom-notebook-services.js`

Comment: Try using the `~` in other links too. See how that works out

Comment: wierd is showing 404: `domain.com/Controller/~/Scripts/custom-notebook-script.js` .

Comment: Try it as `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/custom-notebook-script.js")"></script>`

Comment: right, if I absolutely have to....I will use that, but I am calling a javascript file from a javascript file. So razor syntax won't do any good there.

Comment: Then the `~` won't work there

Comment: If you have a DOM element you can insert the url there `data-url="~/Scripts/script.js"` and pull it into your javascript. Otherwise, drop the leading directory separator.

Comment: Jasen, thanks for the comments, I think that helped. 

I am probably going to call the script on the html page (wrapping it in a event handler so the time works the way I needed it). 

Basically what you are suggesting above (calling the script from html, even though it is not how I really wanted to do it).

Comment: ahh. excuse me. I see what you are saying. leave the path in the html and grab it. problem is not matter what I do it includes the `Controller` in the url...... unless I call the entire domain, which would work.

Comment: What does `@Url.Content("~/Scripts")` print? Is `Controller` the name of your app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to get the path from the Razor helper into your script is through a data attribute.

```
<body data-script-dir="@Url.Content("~/Scripts")">
```

Now extract that in your javascript but you'll need to delay your script until DOM loaded.

```
$(function() {
    var scriptDir = $("body").attr("data-script-dir");   //  "/Scripts"
});
```

then you can append the rest of your path to that string.

Comment: I am upvoting Jasen's, this may be close....
you would probably need to concatenate a full domain url into the `data-script-dir` using the method above and building the path using http://stackoverflow.com/a/21226409/3023642

. For my purpose, I used a work around. This is a very strange problem! jQuery seems not to play well with MVC virtual directories.

Answer (score 2):

You have the virtual directory well configured on IIS?
On the same directory you have the page that contains this `<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/custom-notebook.js"></script>`, you should have a virtual directory pointing to "Scripts" on that same directory of the page.

Comment: Right, so your saying `Script` dir should be in the virtual directory `root` yes? 

That is what I am doing.