# Letsencrypt acme-challenge on wordpress or asp.net mvc

Tags: wordpress, lets-encrypt

I have been trying without success to generate security certificates for my company using Let's Encrypt. My company uses WordPress 3.9.7 for its main website and I am not allow to upgrade to a newer version since that is handled by a third party company. 
The website is running on top of Internet Information Services 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2.
My question is: How can I make wordpress handle http://www.company.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/mftvrU2brecAXB76BsLEqW_SL_srdG3oqTQTzR5KHeA
?
I have already created a new empty page and a new template that returns exactly what let's encrypt is expecting but wordpress keeps returning a 404 for that page. My guess is that the problem arise with the dot(.) at the beginning of the route (".well-known") but I don't know how to solve that on wordpress.

I am also able to use an asp.net mvc website and make IIS point to that website for a while. Not a good idea though since clients may not be able to reach our website for a few minutes, but still an option. Then the question is: How can I create a controller or a route with a dot(".") at the beginning of the name?
Help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the dot with `%2E`?

Comment: Could you elaborate @mevius? My wordpress skills are very basics.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For ASP.Net MVC or Web Forms, with certain Routing configs, you'll end up treating this URL as something for the Routing Engine to hand off to the MVC/Forms Handler, not a static file return. The result will be a 404 or a 503. The solution is surprisingly very simple:

If you haven't already, place the Challenge file:

1. Create the necessary dirs - `.well-known` is tricky [mostly because Microsoft is lazy](https://superuser.com/q/64471/101698), but you can either do it from cmdline or create the folder as `.well-known.` and [Windows Explorer will notice the workaround and remove the trailing period for you](https://superuser.com/a/406758/101698).
2. Inside `\.well-known\acme-challenge` place the challenge file with the proper name and contents. You can go about this part any way you like; I happen to use Git Bash like `echo "oo0acontents" > abcdefilename`

Then make a Web.Config file in the acme-challenge dir with these contents:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <clear />
            <mimeMap fileExtension = ".*" mimeType="text/json" />
        </staticContent>

        <handlers>
            <clear />
            <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule" 
            resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />  
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Source: https://github.com/Lone-Coder/letsencrypt-win-simple/issues/37

Done. The file will start returning instead of 404/503 allowing the Challenge to complete - you can now Submit and get your domain validated.

Aside: The above code snippet sets the content-type to json, a historical requirement that is no longer relevant to letsencrypt. The current requirement is there is no requirement - you can send a content-type of pantsless/elephants and it'll still work.

## More for Asp.Net

I like to redirect all HTTP requests back to HTTPS to ensure users end up on a secure connection even if they didn't know to ask. There are a lot of easy ways to do that, until you're using LetsEncrypt - because you're going to break requests for .well-known. You can setup a static method in a class, like this:

```
public static class HttpsHelper
{
    public static bool AppLevelUseHttps =
#if DEBUG
        false;
#else
        true;
#endif

    public static bool Application_BeginRequest(HttpRequest Request, HttpResponse Response)
    {
        if (!AppLevelUseHttps)
            return false;

        switch (Request.Url.Scheme)
        {
            case "https":
                return false;

#if !DEBUG
            case "http":
                var reqUrl = Request.Url;
                var pathAndQuery = reqUrl.PathAndQuery;
                // Let's Encrypt exception
                if (pathAndQuery.StartsWith("/.well-known"))
                    return false;
                // http://stackoverflow.com/a/21226409/176877
                var url = "https://" + reqUrl.Host + pathAndQuery;

                Response.Redirect(url, true);
                return true;
#endif
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Now that can do a great job of redirecting to HTTPS except when LetsEncrypt comes knocking. Tie it in, in Global.asax.cs:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs ev)
    {
        HttpsHelper.Application_BeginRequest(Request, Response);
    }
```

Notice that the bool returned is discarded here. You can use it if you like to decide whether to end the request/response immediately, true meaning, end it.

Finally, if you like, you can use the AppLevelUseHttps variable to turn off this behavior if need-be, for example to test if things are working without HTTPS. For example, you can have it set to the value of a Web.Config variable.

Comment: HOLY COW!!! Thank you so much. My specifics were different than those of zaidorx, but after four hours of banging my head against the concrete, your solution completely resolved my issue with SSL - MVC on GoDaddy hosting.

Comment: When hosting the application on AppHarbor, this won't work - it produces a 404.