# Set extension for Challenge file using getssl

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lets-encrypt

I am using getssl to create a SSL from lets-encrypt.  I think I have everything setup correct but am running into an issue with the Challenge file. The server I am using MVC on Windows on Liquid Web is not letting me use a file without an extension.  If I add .txt to the challenge file it works correctly, so I know the file is accessable.

So I see two choices:  First is to have getssl add a file extension to the Challenge file.  Second is to allow files without extensions under MVC/Windows.

I have tried changing the web.config file and also looking for changes to the setting but neither have been fruitful.

http://my.site.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/WLasfaweaefqwwqetfgewfweqrtfwefwefsefasdfasdf_W1nuoZqCWbHTU

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here finally:

[Letsencrypt acme-challenge on wordpress or asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34770904/letsencrypt-acme-challenge-on-wordpress-or-asp-net-mvc)

Add the config file in the directory you want to download the file from.