# How to Write an If Statement Based on Current Page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

How can I write an if statement based on the current page? I need to have one that says: If not on `This Page` redirect `here`. There is more to it to check who is logged in, but that part is already handled. Just trying to limit access to one page.

Comment: Webforms? MVC? Some other kind of page?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Sorry. Webforms. Updated my tags.

Comment: Is this part of a master page? And what is the context where you do this: in the code behind? Which page event?

Comment: Also adding the asp.net tag. Some C#'ers here will jump in on asp.net vb questions, but they won't know about it unless they see that tag.

Comment: Your question lacks a lot of info and is difficult to understand. What are the conditions for blocking access? A user role, a specific url, a certain time of day, the alignment of the stars?

Comment: @VDWWD I just want to know how I can use specific a page in an if statement. As in if on "website/thispage.apsx" then redirect. Specific url is fine if that is the way to do it. I don't have any clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do something like this

```
if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("Page1.aspx"))
{
    //do something
}

if (Request.RawUrl.ToLower().Contains("partofurl"))
{
    //do something
}
```

`Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` gives you the full url
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48651567`

But `Request.RawUrl` only gives the path without the domain
`/questions/48651567`

But there are a lot more `Request` options, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21226409/5836671) for more.

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much!