# .Request.Url.Host doesn't show subdomain

Tags: c#, asp.net, binding, asp.net-4.0, httpcontext

I've setup the binding in my applicationhost.config to have subdomain working for my project which I test locally.

```
 <bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:62914:localhost" />
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:62914:de.localhost" />
 </bindings>
```

I can access the site via the subdomain and see it running on localhost.

I want to be able to read the subdomain. I used the following code.

```
 var host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
 var index = host.IndexOf(".");
 string[] segments = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery.Split('/');

  if (index < 0)
    return null;

  var subdomain = host.Substring(0, index);

  return subdomain;
```

The problem is that `HttpContext.CurrentRequest.Url` doesn't have the subdomain in the string.

How can I read the subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

with Request.Url.AbsoluteUri you can get complete URL including subdomain. 
Complete methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21226409/1745142).