# How to know the caller route for Index of a controller in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

So I have a something like this in my cshmtl:

```html
<div>
    <a href="/cars"></a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="/bikes"></a>
</div>
```

So it goes to cars controller and hits the function below:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("cars")]
[Route("bikes")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //here I want to set up if else depending on if cars got called or bikes
    return View();
}
```

In the index function, I wanna know through some if else which route got called. Maybe using view bag or something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the full url of the page I am on in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40680/how-do-i-get-the-full-url-of-the-page-i-am-on-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I you need different logic, then use different actions. refactor the commonalities in to separate methods

Answer (score 0):

The request context should have all the information you need.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("cars")]
[Route("bikes")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var requestUri = Context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

    return View();
}
```

Here are the relevant documentation pages:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext?view=netframework-4.8
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest?view=netframework-4.8
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netframework-4.8