# how to get url entered by the user with domain?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to get the complete URL entered by the user in the browser obviously with the correct domain name. For example, if my domain is **[www.TestDomain.com](http://www.TestDomain.com)** and the user enters the correct domain but with some extra parameters like **[www.TestDomain.com/Test/1124/tres](http://www.TestDomain.com/Test/1124/tres)**. This new URL causes 404 error so i want to get this URL in the controller action method.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46311534/6621862

Comment: @Luke its only returning the controller and the action method name not the complete URL in the browser.

Comment: Try this `var location = new Uri($"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host}{Request.Path}{Request.QueryString}"); var url = location.AbsoluteUri;`